# wine not launching

Tags: wine, winetricks

I have installed wine from the Ubuntu software but it doesn't launch. 
I need your help on how to launch and start using it because i want to install IDM to download videos and some documents since it is quick.
Thanks in advance for your help me guys.

Comment: There are many native alternatives to do the same, as good or better then IDM. And Wine doesn't need to be launched. At best, occasionally we need to open Wine settings to change something, but for the most part we open Windows installers *with* Wine.

Comment: like which native software ? becuase if you want to tell me UGET, i have tried but it doesn't download most of the videos. Thanks though@GabrielaGarcia

Comment: Also when I open downloaded IDM with other applications, i cant find Wine in my installed applications so as to run IDM

Comment: youtube-dl (CLI), java based JDownloader, dozens of Firefox and Chrome addons, etc. ... But  regarding you question, once installed, Wine is automatically associated with .exe and .msi and probably others. So, apparently, you didn't install Wine. Please [edit] and describe what you tried to install Wine (it should be as simple as installing it with Ubuntu Software ).